# multiline variable definitions not working in Makefile

Tags: makefile

I'm trying to use a [multiline variable definition in my Makefile](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Multi_002dLine.html), and it doesn't seem to be working for me:

```
$ cat Makefile
define foo =
I'm a little teapot
short and stout
here is my handle
here is my spout
endef

all:
    echo "$(foo)"
$ make all
echo ""

$ make --version
GNU Make 3.81
Copyright (C) 2006  Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

This program built for i386-apple-darwin11.3.0
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
define foo
I'm a little teapot
short and stout
here is my handle
here is my spout
endef

$(info $(foo))


all:
    echo the shell dislikes multiline variables
```

The `=` following the name of the variable being defined doesn't seem to work in `define` statements in 3.81, and if you *echo* a multiline variable, the shell will interpret the lines after the first one as *commands*.